# How to perform grep onto the output of ldd properly ?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

```
# ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffc1fe000)
    libavfilter.so.0 => not found
    libpostproc.so.51 => not found
    libswscale.so.0 => not found
    libavdevice.so.52 => not found
    libavformat.so.52 => not found
    libavcodec.so.52 => not found
    libavutil.so.49 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdd18259000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdd1803a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdd17c75000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdd18583000)
```

I am trying to grep only the names left from the "=>" symbol.

It works with echo easily:

```
echo linux-vdso.so.1 | grep -oP "^[a-z0-9.]*"
linux-vdso.so.1
```

But when I perform the same RegEx onto the output of ldd it does display anything:

```
ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep -oP "^[a-z0-9.]*"
```

So I thought, maybe I have to include some whitespace

```
ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep -oP "^([a-z0-9.]|\w)*"
```

But, this did not work and so I do not know further...

Comment: Why not `awk '{ print $1 }'`?

Comment: works fine, I am just curious about this white-space thing, because the output of the command is strangely shiftet to the right, and I fought I might be able to catch it with the \w whitespace-class , but it does not work.  I wanted to use the grepped names as input to apt-get in order to install all the missing ones automatically.

Comment: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution for this is to use `awk`:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/ppdhtml | awk '/ => / { print $1 }' | head -n1
libcupsppdc.so.1
```

To do this using `grep`, you will need to use the `lookahead` and `lookbehind` features of PCRE:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/ppdhtml | grep -Po '(?<=\t).+(?= => )' | head -n1
libcupsppdc.so.1
```

The lookahead and lookbehind features affect that match, but are not *included* in the match. Also note that this would not work if `ldd` used a variable number of spaces instead of tabs at the start of the line. Lookbehinds can not have a variable length.

Comment: perfect, lookbehind and lookahead are good friends on both sides, thanks for teaching a nitwit some trick.

Comment: @jordanm: I don't think lookahead and lookbehind make sense here, since when we can easily match with simple regex.

Comment: @cuonglm the simple regex from your example leaves the leading tabs and produces a line that only contains a tab.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility, use cut:

$ cat junk.txt

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffc1fe000)

```
libavfilter.so.0 => not found
libpostproc.so.51 => not found
libswscale.so.0 => not found
libavdevice.so.52 => not found
libavformat.so.52 => not found
libavcodec.so.52 => not found
libavutil.so.49 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdd18259000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdd1803a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdd17c75000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdd18583000)
```

$ cat junk.txt | cut -d'=' -f1

libavfilter.so.0

```
libpostproc.so.51 

libswscale.so.0 

libavdevice.so.52 

libavformat.so.52 

libavcodec.so.52 

libavutil.so.49 

libm.so.6 

libpthread.so.0 

libc.so.6 

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdd18583000)
```

Comment: If you want to exclude exclude /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep '=' | cut -d'=' -f1

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `\s` instead of `\w` (which match a word character) to match any single character considered whitespace, include `[\t\n\f\r ]`:

```
ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep -oP "^([a-z0-9.-]|\s)*"
```

or:

```
ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep -oP "^\s*[a-z0-9.-]*"
```

Comment: The `cut` example is incomplete. He wants to exclude `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` from the output.

Comment: @jordanm: removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This handles shared objects that have white spaces in the file names

```
ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep -Po '(?i).+ => \K.+(?= \([A-F0-9]x[A-F0-9]+\))'
```